# How to export vertex colors or vertex group as polygroup for export?

Tags: export, vertex-groups, vertex-paint

I would like to know how is the correct process to export a 3D model with correct "vertex group" or "vertex color"  to use in zbrush as polygroups to make my work easy.

1 - first of all I modelled this bucket in blender to use as Insert multimesh.

[image]

2 - the next step is create a "vertex paint" ?.

[image]

3 - then I go for export menu ,  choose as obj file , but before , I apply 0,0,0 to (r,l,s transformations) and go to this tab (check if this board are correct , I do not know what's the effects in those blue box I ve marked).

[image]

4 -  Now , In zbrush there are not polygroup (one for the strap , one for the metal button and one for the main bucklet , I just see only one polygroup for all the object see the image).

5 - the most quick solution is to separate the mesh in zbrush and create differents polygroups manually for every bucket and his pieces, metal button and main strap. but I prefer to use blender with group previously.

[image]

Comment: For those unfamiliar with zbrush I suggest including a description of what a polygroup is and what it's meant to do.

Answer (score 3):

[image]Go to *Edit Mode* and select what you want to Polygroup.

Go to *Object Data* tab and click plus next to *Vertex Group* then assign with your selection active and name if you like.

On obj export make sure the *Polygroup* box is checked.
[image]
[image: Zbrush polygroup from Blender]

ZBrush doesn't use smoothing like Blender does you need to subdivide to make it look smooth.

Comment: do you mean , enter to edit mode? and in edit mode I paint o select the geometry  that I need to polygroup (terms of polygroup does not exist in blender's 3D viewport) but still in exporting's tab option?  and how can I send my 3D model with "smooth" obj and not flatten? I must check "smoot group" too .? thx.