# I can't export vertex colors anymore in Blender 3.2

Tags: export, vertex-colors

I just upgraded from Blender 3.1 to 3.2 because I was excited about the changes to vertex colors but I've been disappointed to find that none of the exporters support them. Currently I'm exporting a model with Color Attributes -> Color - Face Corner + Color.

Am I missing something?

Edit 1: seems like "Face Corner + Color" isn't supported but "Face Corner + Byte Color" is when exporting. Any ideas on exporting with linear color?

Edit 2: setting the byte color attribute isn't exporting when set by geometry nodes.

Edit 3: my goal is to color vertices with the center positions of triangles in geometry nodes so that I can reproduce them exactly in Unity. This was working but imprecise in previous versions and in 3.2 the whole process seems to have changed without documentation. So far in Unity I've tried using FBX, GLB and importing the Blender file directly. None of them seem to import colors made with Geometry Nodes. All of them only export color correctly but imprecisely when using "Face Corner + Byte Color."

Edit 4: The imprecision in vertex colors has something to do with the SRGB color space. If you bring each component of a color to power 2.2 (gamma) in geometry nodes it corrects the color pretty well for export as FBX in version 3.1.

Comment: You can export polygroups to an `.obj` file

Comment: That sounds really cool @kemplerart can I do that with any model? & is that the setting "Objects as OBJ Groups" in the obj exporter? & How do I transfer my vertex colors into those groups?

Comment: AFAIK you are correct. None of the exporters were updated for new color attributes.

Comment: Bummer!! Seems like the best thing for me to do is just stick to 3.1 -- I thought that 3.2 would be a nice improvement in precision over 3.1 with the new color mode. I guess I'll just have to wait a few versions...

Answer (score -1):

If you only need data of specific vertex groups, you can create them based on the vertex colors assigned. After, export vertex groups using OBJ export:

Option `Polygroups` under the `Geometry`
[image]

related info: [How to export vertex colors or vertex group as polygroup for export?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96966/how-to-export-vertex-colors-or-vertex-group-as-polygroup-for-export)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This doesn't fix my problem unfortunately. I was able to confirm that changing vertex colors made no difference in my exported OBJ file in 3.2 with these settings.

Answer (score -1):

In Blender 3.3.0 none of the new attributes are written to any export formats.  You can test this by exporting and re-importing back into Blender.  It looks like they have yet to integrate the new attributes into to exporter.
In unity, you can check the inspector window when selecting the mesh in the assets window.[image]

Comment: That's what I'm noticing too! It's a bummer Bc all the attributes seem like they'd be nice to have.